# jquery js import to iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page that uses jquery ui's tabs. Each tab content is an iframe with a local page in it. These local pages have been importing their own jquery.js when their parent also have jquery.js imported.

Is there any way i can use the parents jquery inside the iframes, so I dont have to add jquery.js to every single page inside the iframe?

I know parent.$ may work, but I dont want to call parent on every function. Can i instantiate the jquery object from the parent?

Comment: Why are you using iframes? This sounds like a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put this on the Iframe and you are done...

```
var $ = function() {
   var args = [arguments[0], document];
   return parent.$.apply(null, args);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var $ = parent.$`, or something along those lines, at the beginning of your javascript.

Comment: That was the first thing i tried. As far as I can remember, it did not work correctly. Will try again though

Comment: Doesn't work. The context html being searched with selector will be outside the iframe, the parent.

Comment: In that case, if your frame id was "frame" for example, you could put `$iframe = $('#frame').contents();` at the beginning, and use it in your selectors as follows `$('tag.someclass:someselector',$iframe)...`